# Y appium restarts application in a loop in ios simulator?

Tags: appium

I tried to run test ipa. But appium restarts the app in a loop and produces this error.

> [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: Failed looking up pid of launched process

What should I do to diagnose the root cause and solve the issue?

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: I dreamed up the question you forgot to ask. See if this is what you had in mind. If not hit [edit] and improve it your self.

Comment: well this  is exactly what i wanted to ask thank you.

Comment: @Gaurav this is my log file http://www.mediafire.com/view/20de7bxerrek5kg/logfile_1.docx

Answer (score 4):

Inside your Xcode>Derived Date>build>products, You will have folders as shown. Each will have the respective builds generated. Build for the device might not work for a simulator.

Be very choosy here ;)

[image]

Comment: Yes, the Debug-iphonesimulator worked. However I have to manually build and copy it from a deep directory. Would anybody share the xcodebuild command line argments to create a debug archive for iphone simulator. The following are mine that not worked ~~~ xcodebuild -workspace Firebear.xcworkspace -scheme Firebear -configuration debug CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=$(CompileOutputPath) -destination generic/platform=iOS archive -archivePath $(ArchivePath)

Answer (score 2):

The specific build of the app you are trying to run on the simulator is not built for x86 arch. iOS on device runs on ArmV7, so when a build that is intended for a physical device tries to run on the simulator it will fail. You can see evidence of this in one of the errors printed out in your log

```
info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Mar  9 10:21:51 Arslans-Mac-mini  
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.BFF4C60D-DF35-4ACB-B989-
A8CA8F43139E.launchd_sim[6333 
(UIKitApplication:com.vizteck.Testing123[0x1249][6382]): Program specied by
service does not contain one of the requested architectures:
```

Comment: it does run on simulator  perfectly without appium . And how can i make build for Armv7?Im new to this world of testing and iOS .

Comment: If you are using Xcode gui, in the top left you should see a button that says what device you want to run the app on after building. Select that to open the drop down. If you have an iOS device connected it should appear in that list, otherwise it will just say "iOS Device" either way this is the option you want to select. Do not select one of the simulators. Next click Product (in the top bar), and then choose Archive. You will do this to build the app for device. Once the build finishes a new window will open for export. The export should create an .ipa and you should be able to use that.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message in the simulator because I had not build the project with arguments for simulator.
I solved my problem by building as following

---

```
xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator8.4 \
    -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace \
    -scheme Dobby \
    ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO \
    TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY=1 \
    DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION=YES \
    DSTROOT=$(WorkPath)/appium
```

---