# Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: Failed looking up pid of launched process

Tags: ios, shell, teamcity, instruments, ios-ui-automation

Launch screen appears and disappears again and again when targeting a simulator. i run those steps on a script:

```
## created an archive
xcodebuild clean archive -workspace APP.xcworkspace -scheme APP -archivePath $ARCHIVE_PATH

## export archive
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath $ARCHIVE_PATH.xcarchive -exportPath $ARCHIVE_PATH -exportFormat APP -exportProvisioningProfile app-App-Adhoc-Distribution

## run the iPhone 6 Plus simulator
xcrun instruments -w "iPhone 6 Plus (8.3 Simulator)"

## install the app on the simalutor
xcrun simctl install booted /pathtoAPP/APP.app

## run test.js
xcrun instruments -w "iPhone 6 Plus (8.3 Simulator)" -t /tmp/UIAutomation/APP.tracetemplate /pathtoAPP/APP.app -e UIASCRIPT "/pathtoTest/test.js"
```

i got this error:

```
Instruments Usage Error : No template (-t) specified
instruments, version 6.3 (57536) usage: instruments [-t template] [-D document] [-l timeLimit] [-i #] [-w device] [[-p pid] | [application [-e variable value] [argument ...]]]
Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: Failed looking up pid of launched process
```

Any ideas?
Cheers

Comment: Try commenting out the first 2 `xcrun` lines, and remove `xcrun` from the last line (just run `instruments`).  Also, normally your tracetemplate is `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850933/y-appium-restarts-application-in-a-loop-in-ios-simulator/30779904#30779904

The first answer here solves the issue.

Comment: No luck for me after I run the first 2 lines and then the 3rd of my own: instruments -w "iPhone 6 Plus (8.4 Simulator)" -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate ~/Firebear6.app , I still got the issue of 'Failed looking up pid of launched process'

Comment: My problem was because my build was not set correctly for simulator SDK, though I got the same error message in the simulator.

Comment: I removed the lines the xcrun and i got the same errors. instruments -w "iPhone 6 (8.4 Simulator)" -t /PATHTOTEMPLATE/APP.tracetemplate /PATHTOAPP/APP.app -e UIASCRIPT "/PATHTOSCRIPT/login.js"