# How do i install .app or ipa into iOS simulator through appium?

Tags: automation, automated-tests, appium, ui-automation, appium-ios

I am facing issue with installing .app and .ipa into my iPad2 simulator using appium. Am using Xcode 7.3 and appium 1.5.2. Here what i have done so far : 
 1. Installed appium and done all the necessary settings to run on simulator. set - app path, bundle id, platform version etc.
 2. Mentioned all these in testng.xml file as well -

```
<test name="iOSAutomationTestingiPad 2">
    <parameter name="platformName" value="iOS" />
    <parameter name="platformVersion" value="9.3" />
    <parameter name="deviceName" value="iPad 2" />
    <parameter name="app" value="/Users/demo/Documents/demoApp/sample.app" />
    <parameter name="serverUrl" value="http://someurl here" /><parameter name="language" value="" />
    <parameter name="locale" value="" />
    <parameter name="bundleId" value="" />
    <parameter name="orientation" value="landscape" />
    <parameter name="noReset" value="true"></parameter>
    <classes>
        <class name = "test.appium.iOS.ipad.localization.TestLocalizationBeforeActivation">
            <methods> 
               <include name="captureScreenShotForActivationScreenPageScreen"/>
               </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

now when i try to launch appium and run my test case it loads app into simulator but keeps on restarting the app but when i install it from xcode once and then run my test case it runs perfectly. I want to install the .app or .ipa file without actually installing from Xcode first time. It is my project requirement to remove the app and install it again. As am new to appium am not able to track what am missing here. Can You help me out with any pointers?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the appium installed .app file keeps restarting the app, appium log would help to debug the issue. Can you attach the log ? (Only the part when the app keeps restarting.)

Comment: @vinayak :thanx  I could resolve that issue. I was not giving the correct .app file path to appium it was located here - <“/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SavoMobile-app/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator”> so it worked. But if u can help me with device setup i would really appreciate.

Comment: @Mak13, How did you know that .app located in that location? And how it was generated? Could you please let me know? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @ShivakrishnaChippa: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850933/y-appium-restarts-application-in-a-loop-in-ios-simulator this link may help you i had same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use an debug build for iOS automation always , it'll work

Answer (score 0):

In the app path (Appium GUI) instead of giving .ipa path give the .app path of the application.
Below link will help in getting the .app file for iOS app.

[How to get .app file of a xcode application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984727/how-to-get-app-file-of-a-xcode-application)